# Generating Instant Dynamic sitemap.xml without saving it as file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web, seo

I have a web site which provides news that are updated once every 20 mins. I would like to make sitemap.xml dynamically.

If I have a static file, I should update it regularly. Is It a correct approach to create a jsp folder and map it as "sitemap_x.xml"; get the data from my DB and print it as XML format.

I mean :

search_engine_bot --> sitemap.xml --> sitemap_x.xml --> xmlgenerator.jsp -->

```
out.println("<url><loc>myurl.com/content--42924</loc></url>");
```

I will have 500k news soon, so I dont want to save them both DB and file as xml.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by servlet, which has annotation **@WebServlet("/sitemap.xml")**. So, when requesting http://your-site.com/sitemap.xml, servlet generates response in format XML. Inside XML are links from your database.
Like this:

servlet:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/site_map.jsp");

links = getLinksFromDatabase();

request.setAttribute("baseUrl", baseUrl);
request.setAttribute("links", links);

dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

site_map.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">

<c:forEach items="${links}" var="link">
    <url>
        <loc><c:out value="${baseUrl}" />/<c:out value="${link}" /></loc>
    </url>
</c:forEach>

</urlset>
```